# How to add an Image element for the new PageBuilder content-type in Magento2?

Tags: php, module, magento2

So I have created a new content-type `PageBuilderQuote` for `PageBuilder` following the documentation here https://devdocs.magento.com/page-builder/docs/create-custom-content-type/overview.html , however all the elements added are `textarea`, `input` and `select` it doesn't show you how to add an `image` element, I would like to add for example for this `PageBuilderQuote` module, an `image` element to show the `quote_author_image`, but I can't find how to do it in the documentation, can someone help please?

Comment: I answered to this question here already [add image element to content-type PageBuilder in Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/287623/how-to-add-an-image-element-for-the-new-pagebuilder-content-type-in-magento2/287930#287930)